# wp-config.php file is missing?

Tags: wordpress

I use Go Daddy and have had hosting for a while with Wordpress. I wanted to enable wp multisite so I went in searching for the wp-config.php file and it just wasn't there. Does anyone know why it isn't there or any solutions? Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll have to create it yourself. Use `wp-config-sample.php` to see what it has to look like.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Looks perfectly legit to me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, wp-config.php sits in the same folder as your WordPress blog. So, if the homepage of your blog is at mysite.com/blog, so is your wp-config.php.
In some cases it can be inside your public_html folder.
Please search it form the search bar if you cant locate it.

Please do have a look [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/improve-wordpress-securitty-wp-config-php-location/) .